# Noob Measurement Mystery

Tags: measurement, function-generator

[image: Understanding Measuring]

I am taking up electronics and bought some used test equipment. I have been measuring anything and everything, sometimes with unexpected results. Above is one of those cases.

The function generator is outputting a sine wave of 1kHz at 5Vpp. It shows up as expected on the oscilloscope. The multi-meter on the other hand shows 1.77Vac and 0.02Vdc  Perhaps someone here would be kind enough to explain to me why the multi-meter does not display 5Vac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your meter reads AC in \$V_{rms}\$, which is very different from \$V_{pp}\$.

For sinusoidal signals:

\$ V_{rms} = 0.3535 \cdot V_{pp} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \cdot V_{pp}\$

And therefore \$ 5V_{pp} = 1.767 V_{rms} \$

Also, because you've set your DC offset to 0V, the DC average of the sine wave is 0V, hence the \$0V_{dc}\$.

Therefore, both your measurements are exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me.  Would it then be correct to assume that the 120Vac mains voltage at my house would have a peak to peak value closer to 339.46Vpp?

Comment: @Aladio Yes, the mains voltage in your home is 120Vac,rms, and therefore has a Vpk of 120V*sqrt(2) = 169V, and a Vpp of 120V*sqrt(2)*2 = 339V.

Comment: One more reason to treat AC mains with some caution :-)

Comment: I *was* going to say "it's usually the average, not RMS", but then I saw the yellow.